# ACID compliant Database that isn't NoSQL?

Tags: database, sql, nosql

I'm not necessarily asking if a NoSQL database can be ACID compliant, which has been asked here:
[Is there any NoSQL that is ACID compliant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608103/is-there-any-nosql-that-is-acid-compliant)

I'm wondering if we have a database either now or in the future that is wanting or is another option to a traditional RDBMS?

I know NoSQL was supposed to be the big thing and RDBMS were supposed to go by the wayside and so forth (I've read I dunno how many articles on it). But that never really solved the issue of data that was very strict and had to be kept consistent (like bank transactions... stuff like that). So when RDBMS was "supposedly" supposed to go to the wayside... what was supposed to replace this Data that had to be strict?

Comment: RDBMSes will have to get in the going-by-the-wayside line behind FORTRAN.  Film at eleven.

Comment: RDBMS database are the lifeblood of most companies, they aren't going to dissapear. it would cost literally billions of dollars to replace them. NOSQL dbs solve a different problem than relational ones for the most part, they aren't a replacement.

Comment: @HLGEM Disappointing that this was closed as "not a real question" - with a bit of expansion, your comment would've been a good answer.  Note to everyone else:  Stop being so quick on the trigger to close questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Datomic](http://www.datomic.com/) looks promising

> Datomic is a database of flexible, time-based facts, supporting queries and joins, with elastic scalability, and ACID transactions. Datomic can leverage highly-available, distributed storage services, and puts declarative power into the hands of application developers.

From the rationale :

> Datomic is built upon the model of data consisting of immutable values. How can data be immutable? Don't facts change? They don't, in fact, when you incorporate time in the data. For instance, when Obama became president, it didn't mean that Bush was never president. As long as who is president isn't stored in a single (logical) place, there's no reason a database system couldn't retain both facts simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Although [Nuodb](http://nuodb.com) is a RDBMS, I wouldn't consider it traditional. The approach is how to scale a database while still using the SQL language and being ACID. I guess it's the opposite of what you're suggesting, but getting the benefits of RDBMS and NoSQL.